Flip fluids inflow issue
I’m using Blender addon Flip Fluid to generate dripping paint to Obstacle and domain. I have animated the inflow Enable on/off, so the flow of paint stops at frame 25, out of 100.
But the flow around obstacle and domain keep growing in size. How do you match the amount of fluid generated in frames 0-25, to the dripping amount in frame 26-100?
To clarify physics: In frame 0-25 the inflow generates 100 ml of fluid and then stops. In frame 100 the obstacle and domain contain 400ml.

Flip Fluids is a paid addon, you should contact the developers for help. I have no idea how much similarity there is between this addon and Blender Mantaflow fluid simulation, but there you have a setting in the domain under Liquid that's called Particle Radius. If you hover your mouse over it, the tooltip says: "Particle Radius factor. Increase this value if the simulation appears to leak volume, decrease it if the simulation seems to gain volume." (hint: in my experience it always gains volume with the default value 1). Maybe Flip Fluids has something like that, too?

Thanks. I'll check the addon for this or switch to the Blender fluid simulation.

I don't know if switching is the best option... I mean, I guess you spent some money on Flip Fluids and as far as I know from videos, it is superior to Mantaflow... for a single setting it might not be worth switching. I'm pretty sure there must be something similar, I just cannot answer your question because I have no paid addons, and in general developers who create paid addons should provide support for their addons so you should ask them for help with this.
